# Deallocation of passed in pointer in descructor

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
    public:
        A(){ };
        ~A(){ };

        //stuff
};

class B
{
    public:
        B(A* a){ pA = a;}
        ~B(){ };

        A* pA;
};

int main()
{
    A instOfA = A();

    B instOfB = B(&instOfA);

    return 0;   
}
```

I am unsure as to whether ~B() should delete its pointer data member *pA. I.e.

```
~B()
{
    if(pA!=nullptr) delete pA;
}
```

My guess is that a deletion is needed because B is allocating it in A* pA.

Comment: The question you have to ask yourself is : Does `B` own the object pointer to by `B::pA;`? In this case it points to `instOfA` which is a local variable in `main()`. A local variable is always owned by it's scope. You only ever `delete` something that was allocated with `new`.

Comment: _My guess is that a deletion is needed because B is allocating it in A* pA._ ``B``'s constructor allocate nothing in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all about the ownership and thereby the question is a design question. You are not dynamically allocating A so I would not let B touch it though. It will be deleted in the end of the main.

If you would allocate an instance of A dynamically (`A* instOfA = new A();`
), then you could choose if you want to pass the ownership of that instance to B and have B deleting it.

> My guess is that a deletion is needed because B is allocating it in A*
>   pA.

Your guess is not right. B is not allocating A. All it does is to take a pointer of the instance that was allocated in the main.

Comment: That's (one of the reason) why you should avoid raw pointer and use reference and smart pointer instead: they are more explicit about the ownership.

Answer (score 0):

You're guess is incorrect, since

```
B instOfB = B(&instOfA);
```

passes the address of an `A` of automatic storage duration to `B`s constructor.   Operator `delete` can only be safely used to destroy an object that was created with the corresponding operator `new`.  Using operator `delete` to destroy an object that was NOT created with the corresponding operator `new` gives undefined behaviour.

`instOfA` is guaranteed to cease to exist when `main()` returns, so no action is needed to destroy it.  And any action which results in it being destroyed twice (so its destructor is called twice on the same object) also gives undefined behaviour.

Generally speaking, it would often be better to design your class `B` so it manages the `A` completely (e.g. manage its lifetime) to ensure consistency.     By accepting a pointer, it is not possible to prevent (other than by strident documentation, and relying on programmers heeding the documentation) an object being passed to the constructor that the destructor does not handle correctly.

If you are going to do `delete pA`, it is not necessary to test that `pA` is non-NULL.   The standard specifies that the `delete` operator has no effect on a `NULL` pointer.